# Solution for javascript:history.go(-1) with fancy box iFrame

Tags: php, javascript, xhtml, fancybox

I have build a website for job apply.

[digimobjobs.com](http://manjeri.org/jobs.php)

when click job 'apply direct' working as fancybox iFrame.
after closing iFrame box.
back button needs to click twice instead of one

I'm using javascript to go back

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

I need to keep javascript:history to  GET data

any one help me please

Comment: The link you posted is just returning "internal server error"

Answer (score 0):

Your link is giving an Internal Server Error.

Instead of "going back" you should probably use Javascript to redirect it to that previous page. Try this, replacing it with the name of the page you want to go to:

```
javascript:window.location="twostepsback.html";
```

Comment: u can access the link now
 I can not use direct link address because. `$_GET` search will be removed if I use direct link